# Magento 2.2.3 - Can't get the URL of logo from core_config_data

Tags: magento2, store-view, object-manager, store-switcher

I was trying to pull the **logo_src** from the database table **core_config_data** but can't return it on the frontend. I was trying to do this via objectManager and know that this is not the correct way. However I want to test if the idea that I have works. The odd thing is I can get all other values except this one.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$conf = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('design/header/logo_src');
```

What I eventually want to achieve is to combine this with the storeswitcher and do something like this. In this way I can get the uploaded logo's from each store and display it in an overview.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$conf = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('design/header/logo_src', $block->getCurrentStoreId()
```

I know the Magento 1 equivalent (*see the code below*), but find it hard to translate this to Magento 2. Does anybody have a solution for me?

```
Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl(Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_src', $storeId));
```

Current code

```
    <?php foreach ($block->getGroups() as $_group): ?>
    <?php if (!($_group->getId() == $block->getCurrentGroupId())): ?>
        <a href="#" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getTargetStorePostData($_group->getDefaultStore()) ?>'>
            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_group->getName()) ?>
        <?
            $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $logo = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo');
            echo $logo->getLogoSrc();           
        ?>                  
        </a>        
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it took a while but finally got it working the only thing left is to convert it to a Magento module without objectManager. If anyone has some adjustments to make it better please have a go.. :)

```
            <?php
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $storeID = $_group->getDefaultStoreId();
                $folderName = \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image\Logo::UPLOAD_DIR;
                $storeLogoPath = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('design/header/logo_src', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeID);
                $path = '<img src="/pub/media/' . $folderName . '/' . $storeLogoPath . '"/>';
            ?>
            <?=
                $path;
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$logo = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo');
echo $logo->getLogoSrc();
```

Comment: Hi, This gives me the same effect as the following code which I added already. <?= $block->getLayout()->getBlock('logo')->getLogoSrc() ?>

Comment: It shows the same logo URL over and over and over

Comment: What do you want then? You want logo store wise?

Comment: Exactly, that is what i want to achieve :)

Comment: On which file you are trying to call this code?

Comment: The file I'm trying to do this in is \Magento_Store\templates\switch\stores.phtml

Comment: Did you update the logo for both store views?

Comment: All stores have their own logo's imported under their header tab

Comment: Do you know how I could achieve this?

Comment: Yes its also works fine on stores.phtml Please try to clean the magento cache and try again.

Comment: Well the code by itself does what it should do which is get the logo url but what it doesn't do is get the logo url from the correct store view. I added the code in the foreach loop which gets store specific data but I'm still getting the logo url from the current storeview. I added an example to my question of how the code currently looks.